# AIY authorization Error running voice/assistant_grpc_demo.py

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-aiy

Have setup the RPi Zero Wireless, with AIY kit and projects, and have setup Voice Kit Google Project and enabled Google assistant, and setup user credentials(OAuth)

Running the voice/assistant_grpc_demo.py  demo presents the https: link with brings up the google log in screen.  Clicking the the correct user account, results in an Authorization Error Page: Error 403: access_denied.

The client id is correct in the 'Request Details'  so it appears the demo python code is finding the credentials json file correctly.

So now I am stuck trying to figure out why I am getting  'access denied' error?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the AIY setup instructions fail to mention about adding Test Users to the OAuth Consent screen.

So just added myself as a Test User, and the HTTPS link now worked to Allow for access permissions.

To add a Test User, go to the google cloud console (https://console.cloud.google.com/)  select your Voice Kit project, from the menu select `APIS & Services, OAuth consent screen, Test users`

from there you use the `+ ADD USERS` button to add a test user.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about where on the google api site to do this please. I'm trying to figure this out too.

Comment: @yangliu2  just updated the the answer with  location in the google cloud console, where you can add a Test User